# Timeout and count control with asyncio

Tags: python, parsing, python-asyncio

I just try to use asynchronous script for parsing with asyncio. I find the similar question and took [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68262936/12350924) answer as pattern for my tasks. I added latency for requests (1st part of linked answer) and also tried to add a counter of active requests(2nd part). But this code launch just 5 requests and after become to wait.
I didn`t find good explanation for me how asyncio.Event works, so I would like to ask you to help me to improve my code. Thank you in advance.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio 
import aiohttp 

active_calls = 0
MAX_CALLS = 5

def write_to_txt_file(text, name):    
    f = open(f'{PATH}{name}.txt', 'w')
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

async def getData(item , session, next_delay , event):
    global active_calls, next_delay

    await event.wait()

    if active_calls > MAX_CALLS - 1:
        event.clear()
        next_delay = 0.1

    print( 'start' , active_calls)

    active_calls += 1
    next_delay += DELAY
    await asyncio.sleep(next_delay)
    try:

        async with session.get(url=item['Link'] ) as response:
    
            soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), 'html.parser')
            name = str(item["ID"]) + '. ' + item["Title"][:100]
            text = soup.find(id="begin").get_text()
            write_to_txt_file(text , name)


    finally:
        active_calls -= 1
    if active_calls == 0:
        event.set()


async def parseFromJson(): 
     with open('./data2/csvjson.json') as data_file:         #take links from JSON
        data = json.load(data_file)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: 
            tasks = [] 

            event = asyncio.Event()
            event.set()

            next_delay = 0.1
            DELAY = 0.3
            for item in data:
            
                task = asyncio.create_task(getData(item , session, next_delay , event))
                next_delay += DELAY
                tasks.append(task) 
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def main():
    asyncio.run(parseFromJson())
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

UPD: As I suppose this code can just stop requests but no start it again?

UPD: I have changed my code and now it works like this:

1. All getData() functions launched at one time
2. Script launches 5 requests and stops on 'await event.wait()' line
   rest of them
3. All requests finished and  I start 'event.set()'
4. After this all functions continuous work and rest requests
   started(without limitation of 5 requests).

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just added the loop, and all functions check waiting every time, it seems not correct but it helped me

```
while active_calls > MAX_CALLS:
        print(1)
        await event.wait()
```

[image]